# Deleting Dynamic Element Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

--FieldSection.js--

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Field from './Field.js';

    class FieldSection extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
          numberOfFields: 1
        }
      }
      addField = () => {
        const { numberOfFields } = this.state;
        this.setState({ numberOfFields: numberOfFields + 1 }); 
     }  
      listFields = (numberOfFields) => {
        var fields = [];
        for(var i=0; i<numberOfFields; i++){
          fields.push(
            (<Field number={i} />)
          )
        }
        return fields;
      }

      render () {
        const {listFields, addField} = this;
        const {numberOfFields} = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
              <label><u>Fields</u></label>
              {listFields(numberOfFields)}
              <div id="fieldButtons">
                <button id="addField" type="button" onClick={addField}> Add Field </button>
                <button id="removeField" type="button"> Remove Field </button>
              </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }  

    export default FieldSection;



  -----------------Field.js-------------------
import React from 'react';

class Field extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 'empty',
      specVisible: 'hidden',
      display: 'none'
    };
  }
  SelectChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    if(event.target.value === "string" )
    {
      this.setState({specVisible: 'visible'});
      this.setState({display: 'block'});
    }
    else {
      this.setState({specVisible: 'hidden'})
      this.setState({display: 'none'})
    }
  }
  render (){
    const {SelectChange} = this;
    const {value, specVisible, display} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <label><strong>New Field </strong></label>  
          <div id="remove-" className="remove" style={{display: "inline", visibility: "hidden"}}>
           <label> --Remove </label> <input type="checkbox" id="removeBox" className="rmvCheckbox" /> 
            <br />
          </div>
          <label> Name: </label>
          <input id="name-" className="name" type="text" name="name" /> <br />
          <label> Description: </label>
          <input id="description-" className="description" name="description" /> <br />
          <label> Datatype: </label>
          <select value={value} onChange={SelectChange} id={`selectData-${this.props.number}`} className="selectData" name="selectData" /*onClick={AddListener}*/>
            <option value="empty"> </option>
            <option value="string"> String </option>
            <option value="character"> Character </option>
            <option value="timestamp"> Timestamp </option>
            <option value="integer"> Integer </option>
            <option value="long"> Long </option>
            <option value="double"> Double </option>
            <option value="boolean"> Boolean </option>
          </select> <br />
        </div>
        <div id={`specifySection-${this.props.number}`} className="specifySection" style={{visibility: specVisible, display: display}} >
          <label> Specify Length: </label>
          <input className="specifyLength" type="text" name="length"/> <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
}

export default Field
```

I am trying to implement a feature where you click "Remove Field" button and a list of checkboxes next to all the new fields appears. Whenever you confirm the deletion, it would delete all the elements that are selected.

Obviously I could subtract one to the numberOfFields state, however I want to delete specific elements, rather than just the last field.

What would that look like?

[image: Code Result]

Comment: With being bit larger piece of code, you could add it to some sandbox environment so it is easier to give you solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows. The basic idea is to get all the ids of the fields that need to be deleted and iterate over them and delete all the components corresponding to these ids.

[Sandbox for code](https://codesandbox.io/s/1yxyro8mlj)

- When `addField` is called `fields` state of *FieldsSelection*
  component is updated by adding a key with unique id, with the *Field*
  component as its value along with all the props.
- The `remove` state tracks if remove Field has been clicked and
  toggles the remove checkbox in each *Field* component by passing it
  as a prop.
- `fieldsToRemove` state is updated via the `markFields` prop in
  *Field* component each time a remove field checkbox is clicked.
- When `deleteFields` is called, it iterates over the `fieldsToRemove`
  state and removes the corresponding components from the `fields`
  state object.
- I used `uuid` package for unique ids for each `Field` as opposed to deleting 
  via index, which is not a great way and also conflicts with the key prop of
  react.

**FieldSection.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Field from "./Field.js";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

class FieldSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fields: {},
      remove: false,
      fieldsToRemove: []
    };
  }
  addField = () => {
    const fields = this.state.fields;
    const id = v4();
    fields[id] = <Field key={id} id={id} mark={this.markFields} />;
    this.setState({ fields });
  };
  listFields = () => {
    var ids = Object.keys(this.state.fields);
    return ids.map(id => {
      return React.cloneElement(this.state.fields[id], {
        remove: this.state.remove
      });
    });
  };
  markFields = (checked, i) => {
    if (checked) {
      const arr = [...this.state.fieldsToRemove];
      arr.push(i);
      this.setState({ fieldsToRemove: arr });
    } else {
      const arr = this.state.fieldsToRemove.filter(x => i !== x);
      this.setState({ fieldsToRemove: arr });
    }
  };
  removeFields = () => {
    this.setState({ remove: !this.state.remove });
  };

  deleteFields = () => {
    const fields = { ...this.state.fields };

    this.state.fieldsToRemove.forEach(id => {
      delete fields[id];
    });

    this.setState({ fields, fieldsToRemove: [], remove: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { listFields, addField, removeFields, deleteFields } = this;
    const { numberOfFields, remove } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <u>Fields</u>
        </label>
        {listFields()}
        <div id="fieldButtons">
          <button id="addField" type="button" onClick={addField}>
            {" "}
            Add Field{" "}
          </button>
          <button id="removeField" type="button" onClick={removeFields}>
            {" "}
            Remove Field{" "}
          </button>
          <br />
          <button type="button" onClick={deleteFields}>
            {" "}
            Delete Fields{" "}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FieldSection;
```

**Field.js**

```
import React from "react";

class Field extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: "empty",
      specVisible: "hidden",
      display: "none"
    };
  }
  SelectChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    if (event.target.value === "string") {
      this.setState({ specVisible: "visible" });
      this.setState({ display: "block" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ specVisible: "hidden" });
      this.setState({ display: "none" });
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { SelectChange } = this;
    const { value, specVisible, display } = this.state;
    const styles = this.props.remove
      ? { display: "inline", visibility: "visible" }
      : { display: "inline", visibility: "hidden" };
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>
            <strong>New Field </strong>
          </label>
          <div id="remove-" className="remove" style={styles}>
            <label> --Remove </label>{" "}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="removeBox"
              className="rmvCheckbox"
              onChange={e => {
                this.props.mark(e.target.checked, this.props.id);
              }}
            />
            <br />
          </div>
          <label> Name: </label>
          <input id="name-" className="name" type="text" name="name" /> <br />
          <label> Description: </label>
          <input
            id="description-"
            className="description"
            name="description"
          />{" "}
          <br />
          <label> Datatype: </label>
          <select
            value={value}
            onChange={SelectChange}
            id={`selectData-${this.props.number}`}
            className="selectData"
            name="selectData" /*onClick={AddListener}*/
          >
            <option value="empty"> </option>
            <option value="string"> String </option>
            <option value="character"> Character </option>
            <option value="timestamp"> Timestamp </option>
            <option value="integer"> Integer </option>
            <option value="long"> Long </option>
            <option value="double"> Double </option>
            <option value="boolean"> Boolean </option>
          </select>{" "}
          <br />
        </div>
        <div
          id={`specifySection-${this.props.number}`}
          className="specifySection"
          style={{ visibility: specVisible, display: display }}
        >
          <label> Specify Length: </label>
          <input className="specifyLength" type="text" name="length" /> <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Field;
```

Comment: what is { v4 } from "uuid"?

Comment: It's a function that generates a unique id everytime.